# Dynamic Grid Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, grid-layout

I want to implement grid, which will be populated dynamically. I want to know what is the best approach to implement this Relative layout(List View) or Grid Layout?

[image]

Comment: Grid Layout. Good luck.

Comment: Would you please point me to some tutorial, to dynamically generate  the grid. As I don't know the number of rows in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a GridView dynamically.

GridView would contain of ImageView and TextView as per your need. You will have to use your custom adapter. In it's `getView` method, populate the ImageView and TextView.

**Example:**

GridView item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="trebuchet"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

A POJO class for item:

```
public class Item
{
    String title;
    Drawable image;
    //getter setter
}
```

Adapter class:

```
//getView method in your adapter class

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View itemView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (itemView == null)
    {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
        holder.txtItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        itemView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }

    Item item = getItem(position);
    holder.imgItem.setImageDrawable(item.getImage());
    holder.txtItem.setText(item.getTitle());

    return itemView;
}
```

Now add adapter data in your Activity class and then set that adapter to GridView.

[Refer to this](http://sujewan.blogspot.in/2013/08/9-android-custom-gridview.html) and [this](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/gridview.php)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want `GridView`. Easy example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/). In your case, you will need to make an XML layout for each row to accommodate both your TextView and ImageView. Other answers here address that.

Comment: is it possible to place image view & text view inside grid view to achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, easiest way is to make an XML layout which each cell will conform to. Someone has just shown you how.

Comment: Answer should have minimum code or description which describe details of link.

Comment: Copy that. Will do next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `GridView` with a custom adapter. Each time you want the view to update, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.