# Alignment issue when using different screen resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout

please help me to arrange the layouts and elements which is suitable for all devices,
my current xml codes is given below.the main problem is the **elements are changed when it runs on different screen resolutions**`

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="2dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/firstimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/texthere"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="helloooo"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstimage"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/secondimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/texthere2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="helloooo"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/secondimage"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thirdimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/second_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first_row"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fourthimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fifthimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sixthimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/third_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/second_row"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sevimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eighthimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ninthimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/smallcircle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/text9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/workscam"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: 1. RelativeLayout has no property Orientation. 2. Your xml contains error. Fix that first

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ if yor set orientation property in realtive, it didn't work, but also it never throw any error.

Comment: @Bee post screen that you want to design.

Comment: @DroneDev if you see, OP has improper closing opening LinearLayout in his xml. Kindly check properly.

Comment: And put whole xml. This is heading us in wrong way.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ mate, i just told you about orientation property, not about his layout opening closing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67091/discussion-between-magicalphoenix-and-drone-dev).

Comment: @Bee you can edit questions with more details.

Comment: @DroneDev i am not able to upload full codes,something went wrong..can you please give me your mail id???/

Comment: @Bee i want to see screen image that u want to develop via xml, i don't need your code.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ how can i upload full xml code?? shows some formalities..i have the picture of the layout that i want,how can i show you :(

Comment: Upload in tiikoni and paste link in question

Comment: please check the link  http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e9da08d

Comment: I know my xml is not correct,because I am new to this .please help me .and try to give me an exact xml ,the image link is given above

Comment: It will be better if you use GridView fr this layout. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416461/dynamic-grid-layout/27416572#27416572)

Comment: Make image representation of what layout you required and put here.