# How to programmatically create a gridview with ImageButtons and TextViews below the image buttons

Tags: c#, android, gridview, xamarin, android-imagebutton

I'm working on a project and I'm using Xamarin.Android plugin for visual studio 2015 using XML views.  I need to create a screen for the app with ImageButtons layed out like the image below but I'm needing to create this dynamically based on a list that can change what Image Buttons show up.  The end result would look something like the image but less buttons could appear based on what is in the list.   I'm not really sure how to go about this as I haven't worked with GridViews that much much less in xml.  So basically in the code all I've got so far is the populated list :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainMenu);
        List<User> configList = new List<User>(user.Configurations);


    }
```

xml layout Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/LocationsRoot"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/space2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/bottomtoolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbarbottom"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So each imagebutton will have a different image.  Image :

[image]

How do I achieve this programmatically?

Comment: Ultimately, you want a dynamically built grid view with some text under each button?

Comment: Yes and I need to iterate through the list that is shown in my onCreate method in order to build those imagebuttons.

Comment: Might want to use this as a reference guide (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-creating-a-numeric-keypad-with-gridlayout--mobile-8677), yes its in Java but the translation to C# is straight forward.

Comment: But that doesn't really satisfy the dynamic portion of it though.... So the list may only contain two of those buttons but some times the list may contain all eight objects for those buttons...

Comment: yes, loop over your list and then add new image button

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416461/dynamic-grid-layout

Comment: Oh cool that's what I'm looking for.  I've already got a Adapter class.  Put that link as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic way to do it in Java, which is pretty straight forward to convert to C#.

[Dynamic Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416461/dynamic-grid-layout)

You can generate a GridView dynamically.

GridView would contain of ImageView and TextView as per your need. You will have to use your custom adapter. In it's `getView` method, populate the ImageView and TextView.

**Example:**

GridView item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="trebuchet"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

A POJO class for item:

```
public class Item
{
    String title;
    Drawable image;
    //getter setter
}
```

Adapter class:

```
//getView method in your adapter class

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View itemView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (itemView == null)
    {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
        holder.txtItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        itemView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }

    Item item = getItem(position);
    holder.imgItem.setImageDrawable(item.getImage());
    holder.txtItem.setText(item.getTitle());

    return itemView;
}
```

Now add adapter data in your Activity class and then set that adapter to GridView.

[Refer to this](http://sujewan.blogspot.in/2013/08/9-android-custom-gridview.html) and [this](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/gridview.php)

Hope it helps.

**CREDIT:** @JASON G PETERSON