# Recycle-view different column number

Tags: java, android

Hello Can i make like this image with recycle-view layout manger? 
and this image show what i want to do thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: for further clarifications...you can ask me..

Comment: @SantanuSur thank you but can you give a simple code of that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416461/dynamic-grid-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ReycyleView` using `GridLayoutManager`

```
manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
@Override
public int getSpanSize(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return 2; //  Splitting into 2 columns
    } else {
        return 3; // Splitting into 3 columns
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can ...in `recycler_adapter`  check if `position == 0` then make the two cardsview `visible` and set them... and in `else {cardview4 ,cardview5,cardview6 visible` and set them and make cardview1 and cardview2 `Gone` the inflate layout will contain a relative lat
yout with two `horizontal linearlayouts` just `hide make the layouts gone and visible at proper position in onBind()`

Answer (score 0):

for achieving this view i think `GridLayoutManager` with it's `setSpanSizeLookup()` method is the best choice. you can find complete explanation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625600/8063951). In case you face any problem while implementing you can ask.

Comment: how can i implement   //  RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem so that i can solve your problem......i am not getting your point.